# Define new Imagefeatures with yocto

Tags: operating-system, yocto, bitbake, recipe

in yocto imagebuildscripts there is a config variable named "IMAGE_FEATURES" i want to create a custom Imagefeature.

I searched my yocto installation which runs poky for existing imagefeatures but i wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMAGE_FEATURES` is a bit special, as its basically being hardcoded into [image.bbclass](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/classes/image.bbclass).

Generally you are way better off creating custom `DISTRO_FEATURES`, and triggering on them whereever needed. See [`packagegroup-core-boot`](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-boot.bb) as an example of a recipe changing behaviour based on `DISTRO_FEATURE` in various places.

Usage wise there is little difference, the only thing you can't do is set `DISTRO_FEATURES` in the image recipe. If that is your actual need, then you probably should pour the new functionality in a custom image class the includes and extends `image.bbclass`m and call it `myimage.bbclass` (or similar).

EDIT:
Initially, I referred to the [dropbear](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/dropbear/dropbear.inc#n14) recipe as an example that triggers behaviour based on `systemd` being set as `DISTRO_FEATURE`. This is technically correct (and it was the first recipe that came to my mind), but probably confusing as there is a dropbear spedific `IMAGE_FEATURE` too.

Comment: isn't ssh-server-dropbear a imagefeature?